# Fill container without expanding image

Tags: html, css, image

I am currently using `background-image: url()` with `background-size: contain` in order to have an image fill it's container. This works well for large images, as they are automatically reduced in size to fill the space without clipping or stretching the image, irrespective of the relative aspect ratio of the image and the container.

However if the image is smaller than the container in both height and width, the image will be expanded, which often makes the images appear fuzzy or pixelated.
Is it possible in CSS to have smaller images display in their original size, whilst retaining the above behaviour for larger images?

I expect I could code something in Javascript to compare the image and container size, and apply a different style, but I wondered if there was a pure css solution?

This is for a photo gallery type application on a public website so needs to support all the current commonly used browsers.

Comment: Not with `background-size: contain`. CSS can't detect the size of a background image nor is it conditional.

Comment: If the size of the background graphic is known, and the width of the container is, say, only dependent on the window width, you can use a simple media query...

Comment: Doesn't have to be with a background-image. I only changed from <img> to <div> with background image to get the 'contain' functionality. Just wondered if there is a better way?

Comment: WIth <img>, you can set the width and height to auto, and the max-width to 100%. That will restrict the size horizontally. Or, set the max-height, which will restrict the size vertically.

Comment: It is a photo gallery, so will be various sizes of image fed from a database. Might be possible to get image sizes from php, but that's probably more complicated than a javascript solution.
I had thought about using a media-query, but I would need to look at both the width and height I think. There are also some other responsive elements, and I want the large images to be displayed as big as possible, so the size of the container isn't something that can easily be hard-coded.

Comment: Some images are landscape, some are portrait. Screen layout means the container may also be either portrait or landscape. I would therefore need to query both the container size and image size and compare the aspect ratios to know which style to apply. I can probably code this in javascript. Was just wondering if there was an easier pure css way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the background image height with the container element height and apply background-size property accordingly.

See below code OR fiddle

HTML

```
<div id="example1">
<h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
<p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#example1 {
    background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_flwr.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

JS

```
var image_url = $('#example1').css('background-image'),
    image;

// Remove url() or in case of Chrome url("")
image_url = image_url.match(/^url\("?(.+?)"?\)$/);

if (image_url[1]) {
    image_url = image_url[1];
    image = new Image();

    // just in case it is not already loaded
    $(image).load(function () {
     //alert(image.width + 'x' + image.height);

    if($('#example1').height() > image.height ){
        alert("background height is smaller than it's containner height");
            $('#example1').css('background-size', 'auto');
      }   
    });

    image.src = image_url;
}
```

Fiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/ujwu5zvn/
```

Comment: Thanks. As I said in the question, it is possible to change the style in javascript (I think I will want to compare both the width and height though). I just wondered if there was a pure css solution.

Answer (score 0):

#### A pure CSS solution is only possible with different HTML

If you can switch to using `<img>` tags instead of background images, you can make the image stretch the container to certain extent and cut off anything that doesn't fit.

You simply need to turn the logic around and let images be whatever size they want to be initially, up to a limit defined by `max-width`. Images larger than this size will be downscaled to fit the container, while images smaller than this will keep their original size and their container will wrap them nicely.

You can also define a `max-height` on your container to keep your layout tidy and clip the parts of the image that would overflow it.

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="whatever.jpg" class="dont-uglify-pls"
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
    max-width: 10em; /* or whatever limit you want your images to start downscaling at */
    max-height: 10em; /* or whatever your layout looks like */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .dont-uglify-pls {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

#### If you need more content in there

Simply slap `position:relative` on the container and fill it with absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: I don't think this will work without clipping when you have a tall image in a wide container.

Comment: That is true, as I said in the answer clipping will occur after the limit defined by `max-height`.  Always some tradeoffs when dealing with dynamic image resizing for arbitrary content in a single language. :)

Alternatively you can omit the `max-height`, let the images expand to full size and handle the layout on the JS side with something similar to masonry, but then again it is not pure CSS either. :(